Proof, if the left-sided and right-sided limit values are equal, the limit value exists (e-d Definition)
Picture of what needs to be proven
$\forall \epsilon > 0$
I have absolutely no idea how to proof this. Maby you can help me.

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

Why do you use the symbol you used (^) for "logical and" in the statements themselves?

I'll give you a very small example of MathJax, the rest is for you.

I dont know, I thought it was the correct formulation of the problem. When A and B ist true then C must be true and around. I am new in college maths. Is it generally false? How should I rewrite it?

Let $\epsilon >0$. Then there exist $\delta_1 > 0, \delta_2 >0$ such that
$| f(x) - L | < \epsilon$ if $0 < a - x < \delta_1$
$| f(x) - L | < \epsilon$ if $0 < x - a < \delta_2$
If we take $\delta = min \{ \delta_1, \delta_2 \}$ we get
$| f(x) - L | < \epsilon$ if $0 < a - x < \delta$
$| f(x) - L | < \epsilon$ if $0 < x - a < \delta$
Therefore
$| f(x) - L | < \epsilon$ if $0 < | x - a | < \delta$

Please do not answer low effort questions
